# curl init() not support assign variable and Check the url is active or not in php

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I need to check the given short url is active or not. and used the following php function to get the url information, after get the expanded url

example :
$ch = curl_init('https://www.facebook.com');

above code is working show result

$ch = curl_init('$url');

above is not working assign variable please clear write curl_init function

```html
<?php


    if($_POST['submit'])
    {
     

     $url = ($_POST['name']);


     $ch = curl_init('$url');
    echo $ch;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);





    if ($retcode == 200) {
        $isUrlOk = true;
    } else {
        $isUrlOk = false;
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: and what is the value inside $url

Comment: Change `$ch = curl_init('$url')` to `$ch = curl_init($url)`

Comment: $url = 'http://ahobilamtourism.com/';

Comment: If you wrap a variable inside single quotes, it will literally use what you write, so it tries to use the url `$url` and not it's content. When passing variables as function arguments, do as @Pratansyah suggests and just write the variable without any quotes.